# Hiding fragments in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, blending, depth-buffer

I am working with OpenGL-ES 3.0 in Android.

To simplify my issue, I am going to describe a scenario very similar to mine. Let's say that I have a sphere centered at the origin. Let's also say that I have another sphere centered at the origin, with a larger radius. Finally, let's say that I have a cylinder, and the center of the top face of the cylinder is lying on the origin. The cylinder intersects the two spheres. A picture of the scenario is below:

This is my initial setup: 
[image: Initial Setup]

I would like to only draw the section in between the two spheres, as shown below:
[image: Section in Between]

However, in my application, the smaller of the two spheres isn't visible (though it exists). It is completely transparent. Thus, the final end product I would like would look something like this:

[image]

Now, one more piece of information: as I mentioned earlier, this is a simplification of my current scenario. Instead of spheres, I have far more complex objects (not simple primitive shapes). Thus, approaching this from a mathematical perspective (such as only drawing the portion of the cylinder that is greater than the smaller sphere's radius and less than the larger sphere's radius) is not going to work. I need to approach this somehow from a programming perspective (but given my limited knowledge of OpenGL, I can only think of Depth Testing and Blending as viable options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this using a stencil buffer.

I haven't compiled this code and it will need modifying, but this is the general idea:

```
glDisable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );

<Render rest of scene (everything other than the spheres and cylinder)>

// Render the larger sphere into the stencil buffer, setting stencil bits to 1

glEnable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );
glClear( GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT ); 
glColorMask( GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE );  // Don't render into the color buffer
glDepthMask( GL_FALSE );    // Don't render into the depth buffer
glStencilMask( 0xff ); // Enable writing to stencil buffer
glStencilFunc( GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xff );    // Write 1s into stencil buffer
glStencilOp( GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE ); // Overwrite for every fragment that passes depth test (and stencil <- GL_ALWAYS)

<Render big sphere>

// Render the smaller sphere into the stencil buffer, setting stencil bits to 0 (it carves out the big sphere)

glStencilFunc( GL_ALWAYS, 0, 0xff );    // Write 0s into stencil buffer

<Render small sphere>

// Render the cylinder into the color buffer, only where the stencil bits are 1

glStencilMask( 0 ); // Don't need to write to stencil buffer
glColorMask( GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE );  // Render into the color buffer
glStencilFunc( GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xff ); // Only render where there are 1s in the stencil buffer

<Render cylinder>

glDisable( GL_STENCIL_TEST );

// Now render the translucent big sphere using alpha blending

<Render big sphere>
```

Comment: I have a question: I think something is slightly off with the code you have suggested. Let me explain my understanding of your code, and let me know if this is an incorrect understanding:

Comment: So you begin by clearing the buffer and writing 1s everywhere. You then overwrite the places that pass the depth test and replace those values (by the way, replace with what?). Then you write 0s for the 2nd sphere. Then anywhere that there are 1s, the cylinder is drawn, correct?

Comment: I changed your code from GL_REPLACE to GL_ZERO. Doesn't this make more sense? If the depth test passes (in my case, if a fragment passes the depth test, it will be one that lies outside of the large sphere), and the stencil test passes (which it always does), shouldn't I make these values 0 in the buffer?

Comment: The stencil buffer is cleared (with 0s); the big sphere writes 1s into the stencil buffer for each fragment that passes the depth test: `glStencilFunc( GL_ALWAYS, 1, 0xff );` - fragments always pass the stencil test, set ref value = 1, `glStencilOp( GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE );` - if a fragment passes stencil test (and depth test) then replace the existing stencil bit at that pos with ref value (1 in this case); do the same for the small sphere except with ref value 0 (yes you could also do `glStencilOp( GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_ZERO );`

Comment: Then only render fragments into the color buffer if they have stencil value 1 at their positions:  `glStencilFunc( GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xff );`

Comment: I suggest carefully reading the docs [https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glStencilMask.xml](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glStencilMask.xml) and looking around for simpler stencil examples/tutorials, for e.g. [https://open.gl/depthstencils](https://open.gl/depthstencils)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is [Constructive Solid Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry), but with the added complexity of using meshes as one of the primitive types.

Event with only mathematically simple primitives, it is very hard to implement CSG purely in the OpenGL pipeline because you would need to find a way to represent the scene graph in a way that the shaders can understand and efficiently parse.  Once you add in meshes, it's basically impossible because the vertex and fragment shaders won't have easy access to the mesh geometry.

You might be able approximate it by executing a draw call for every item in the CGS graph and with clever manipulation of stencil and depth buffers, but you would probably still end up with lots of edge cases that didn't render properly.